# Column X does not exist. (Created column by function)

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.3 and I'm trying to select all users that have an age of over twenty. I have constructed a SQLFiddle that shows the error:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5cd52/3

**SNIPPET:**

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  name text,
  birthdate bigint
);

INSERT INTO users values('Chris', 774532800000);
```

SQL:

```
SELECT u.*, age(TO_TIMESTAMP(u.birthdate / 1000)) as age from users u
WHERE age > 20
```

ERROR:

```
ERROR: column "age" does not exist Position: 77
```

The reason that I'm deviding by 1000 is because my dates are all stored using `milliseconds` as that's the default by Firebase. This postgreSQL database is used to handle more complex queries that Firebase couldn't.

Comment: Is this Postgresql or MySQL?

Comment: i guess alias for a column cant be used in where clause,because that column will not be evaluated at the time of filtering.

Answer (score 1):

The `age` alias still does not exist when the `where` clause is executed, before the `select` clause. One solution is to check the `age` in an outer query:

```
select *
from (
    select u.*,
        extract(year from age(to_timestamp(u.birthdate / 1000))) as age
    from users u
) s
where age > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
As suggested by @Clodoaldo Neto (I'm new, don't know how to tag), here it is:

```
SELECT *
FROM staging.users u 
WHERE age(to_timestamp(u.birthdate / 1000)) > '20 years';
```

Explanation:

- You need to cast birthdate / 1000 to double
  because to_timestamp only accept double.
- Then when filtering, you need to use '20 years' instead of 20 because the age function returns interval.

Comment: In that case, then remove the cast to double precision.